# Does not load subdomain with nginx configuration

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am hit the wall. I have tried various tutorials, docs ant etc. without success. Below is my Nginx configuration file. I want to have main server on https://example.com and other server on https://api.example.com. Domain example.com should serve React SPA and api.example.com should be backend API. Right now, only example.com is working, but api.example.com doesn't load.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://api.$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example_com__chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/private.pem;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example_com__chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/private.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000; // backend Django app on docker-compose.
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host; 
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /home/app/web/mediafiles/;
    }
}
```

api.example has been added in Route of AWS. Even if I remove proxy part and just try to return string, it does not work.

Comment: Your second `return` statement is wrong, and you have a C++ style comment in your configuration file. Otherwise, use `nginx -t` to test the configuration and add to your question any relevant entries in the access and error logs.

Comment: I have added comment intentionally just here. It does not exist in configuration file. Why second return statement is incorrect?

Comment: $host = “api.example.com” so you don’t need to put “api.” In front of it.